# How to set a default path to download a file in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I've made a downloader that takes an URL and a save file path every time I need to download a file.

I want some help to set a default path in the downloader that downloads every file to that destination place, so that users don't have to give the path every time.

Comment: `My.Settings` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can store default location in application configuration file and populate the location textbox from there.

If user wish to change the location then he can change else files will be saved to that location by default.